# Triple split mapping issue with Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm encountering a strange problem using Doctrine2.

I'm getting the following error:

doctrine orm:validate-schema

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'EmailVerification' mapping is invalid:
* The referenced column name 'id' does not have a corresponding field with this
 column name on the class 'OurUsers'.

[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.
```

My scenario is as follows:

- I have 3 tables sharing a primary key.
- Table `Auth` which holds `user_id` PK.
- Table `OurUsers` for which `Auth.user_id` is shared PK.
- Table `EmailVerification` for which `OurUsers.user_id` is shared PK.
- I also have `NotOurUsers` - hence the split.

Entities are declared as follows:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="auth")
 */
class Auth {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer", name="user_id") @GeneratedValue @var int */
    private $id;

    /* ... */
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="our_users")
 */
class OurUsers {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Auth")
     * @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * @var Auth
     */
    private $id;

    /* ... */
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="email_verification")
 */
class EmailVerification {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="OurUsers")
     * @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * @var OurUsers
     */
    private $id;

    /* ... */
}
```

I'm using Dosctrine 2.1.

**btw** Doctrine 2.2 validates mappings as good, but I get same error at run time as with 2.1.

Comment: what if you change the `referencedColumnName` in EmailVerification to just `"id"`? that way it will referr to the id attribute in OurUsers class, which in terms is refering to the user_id in Auth. i think the problem must be somewhere around that

Comment: tried it before posting here - not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that EmailVerfication points to OurUSers intead of to Auth, the error message is misleading though. I am not sure the triple mapping is possible from the internals (i am pretty sure i implemented an exception for this some where as well, i have to look why this is not triggered).

Comment: switched to v2.2, it tries to convert `OurUsers` to string in `UnitOfWork::tryGetById`. Class it receives looks as the right one to receive.

Comment: can you add a ticket on doctrine-project.org/jira and add the stack trace where this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You tell in your JoinColumn statements that you  work with a `user_id` column.

But your column definition for `OurUser::id` creates a `id` column by default.

You either have to modify the JoinColumn statement to use `id`:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="email_verification")
 */
class EmailVerification {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="OurUsers")
     * @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var OurUsers
     */
    private $id;

    /* ... */
}
```

OR

add a `Column` annotation on `OurUser::id`, like that:

```
     /**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="our_users")
 */
class OurUsers {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Auth")
     * @Column(type="integer", name="user_id")
     * @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * @var Auth
     */
    private $id;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've followed your second solution. And that's the error I got: `Object of class OurUsers could not be converted to string ~ ...\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php`. But at least now it validates. I'll try adding `__toString`, but if it works - it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to switch to something like this, it's a lot more clear and should create less problems:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="auth")
 */
class Auth {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer", name="user_id") @GeneratedValue @var int */
    private $id;

    /* ... */
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="our_users")
 */
class OurUsers {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Auth")
     * @var Auth
     */
    private $auth;

    /* ... */
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="email_verification")
 */
class EmailVerification {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="OurUsers")
     * @var OurUsers
     */
    private $ourUser;

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like that. But, there's a but. What if I can't control the schema? Or even, should I change my DB design because Doctrine 2 can't support triple-split, for whatever reason?